# What kind of agreement needed to work as a contractor for UK company from India

Tags: united-kingdom, india, contractor

If I want to work for UK company as a contractor from India (Remotely Software developer) then Do I need to Make any legal agreement in India or UK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work as independent consultant in India with out any issues. Be sure to declare your income and pay taxes as there will be no TDS.

Consult a CA, you can show certain expenses, e.g laptop, broadband etc and reduce your tax liability.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, you need a written contract.  If you don't have one, then there's not a lot you can do if they refuse to pay you after you have done the work.